# How to merge two for loops into list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

How do I merge these two for loops into list comprehension since I am dealing with large amounts of data. The purpose of this function is to find the number of capital words in a given string. The data that is given is a list of email texts and this is supposed to return a list of numbers (the numbers being the number of capital words in each email thread).

```
def get_capital_prop(data):
    total_capitals = []
    temp = 0

    for i in range(len(data)):
        count = 0
        for word in data[i]:
            count += sum(1 for c in word if c.isupper())
        total_capitals.append(count / len(data[i]))
    return total_capitals
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand correctly that you're looking for the number of words that begine with a capital letter, here's a simple approach:

```
def get_capital_prop(data):
    return len([word for words in data for word in words if word[0].isupper()])
```

This solution assumes every word has at least one letter, and generates a temporary list. It slightly more sophisticated solution could handle zero length words, and get you the number without creating an intermediate list, but this is a good starting point in any case.

Based on the updated description, what you really want is just to get a list of counts of *all* upper case characters in a list of lists of strings. That should look like:

```
def get_capital_prop(data):
    return [len([c for c in email if c.isupper()]) for email in data]
```

Alternatively, avoiding the creation of intermediate lists:

```
def get_capital_prop(data):
    return [sum(1 for c in email if c.isupper()) for email in data]
```

Comment: The data provided is a list of email body texts and the count is to see how many capital letters are in each email body text.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current implementation, I assume that you are after the total number of words that contain *only* uppercase letters.

```
def is_caps(word):
    return word.isupper() and word.isalpha()

def get_capital_prop(data):
    return len([word for words in data for word in words if is_caps(word)])
```

`isupper()` will return `True` if the string contains at least one letter and every letter is upper case.  This ignores any numeric, symbols or special characters that do not have an "upper" or "lower" case.  The helper function `is_caps` checks to see whether a word is both fully capitalized **and** only contains alphabet characters, returning `True` if this is the case or `False` otherwise.

Here is a quick example that I have included:

In:

```
some_text = '''
This is just some EXAMPLE TEXT that
I have put together.  Hopefully this ANSWER
is helpfuL!! 123AA'''

rem = ',!?.\'"()'  # Symbol characters removed from the start and end of words
data = [[word.strip(rem) for word in words.split(' ')] for words in some_text.split('\n')]
```

Out:

```
>>>print(data)  # Only 4 fully capitalized words: EXAMPLE, TEXT, I and ANSWER
[[''], ['This', 'is', 'just', 'some', 'EXAMPLE', 'TEXT', 'that'], ['I', 'have', 'put', 'together', '', 'Hopefully', 'this', 'ANSWER'], ['is', 'helpfuL', '123AA']]

>>>print(get_capital_prop(data))
4
```

If you want to include capitalized words with apostrophes such as *"DON'T"* or *"SHOULDN'T"* in your answer, you can easily alter the logic within the `is_caps()` helper function based on what you desire.

Comment: The data provided is a list of email body texts and the count is to see how many capital letters are in each email body text. Is there a way to do list comprehension on that?

Comment: So `data` is a list of email text bodies?  In that case you would want `get_capital_prop` to return something like: 
`[count_caps(body_text) for body_text in data]`, where `count_caps()` is a function you can define to simply count the number of capital letters in each text body.  You *could* do this purely using list comprehension and sum like so:
`[sum([char.isupper() for char in body_text]) for body_text in data]`, but I don't recommend this for large quantities of data as it would be painfully inefficient.  You're best off just using a counter function for each text body.